# Cytoscape computation time for changing to hierarchical layout extremely slow

Tags: visualization, graph-theory, cytoscape

I'm trying to visualise a network of about 5k nodes and 30k edges in Cytoscape.

I've already built the edgelist with all the attributes in Pandas and NetworkX and I succesfully imported the data in Cytoscape.

The standard visualisation that Cytoscape uses at the end of the import process is rather quick (something like 40, 60 seconds). The zoom and pan works correctly too.

I've tried to apply the Hierarchical layout because I'm working with a quasi-trophic structure ordered by trophic level (who eats who basically) and the process is extremely slow.

At first I've thought that the program was stuck, but after 10 or 15 minutes the progress bar actually moved from the rendering of the nodes position to the "Layering nodes vertically...".
In the first steps of the computation (with the progress bar actually moving and changing description) the cpu usage was about 50% to 70%.

Now at the "Layering nodes vertically..." phase the cpu usage is steady at 20%.

I've awaited something like two to three hours before canceling the hierarchical layout conversion. And after I clicked cancel the software responds correctly and I was able to zoom and pan the network again, so it didn't actually crashed.

It is normal? I need to expect hours of computation time to apply a layout to a graph this size?

I've always worked with networkx and this the first time that I use a network science software for the sole purpose of visualisation. So I really don't have something to compare this performance to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving the yFiles hierarchical layout a try.  I would expect it would work much better.

-- scooter